# APK Ionic 3 Não instala

Tags: node.js, ionic3, apk

Bom dia Galéra

Estou com um problema, consigo gerar o apk com ionic normalmente, porém na hora de instalar no telefone, aparece uma mensagem do play store e diz que o mesmo não conhece os autores co aplicativo, quando clico em instalar assim mesmo, o mesmo diz que o aplicativo não pode ser instalado, se insistir o mesmo diz que já existe um pacote com o mesmo nome, o aparelho esta usando o android 7, podem me ajudar.

Tentei em 2 modelos de telefones diferentes: 1 Moto G5 Plus 2 Sansung Galaxy J7

Ambos com android 7 e acima de 7

Desde já agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você assinou o seu aplicativo?

Comment: Se não me engano, da versão 8.1 ou +, é Necessário pedir permissões ao usuário em tempo de execução da permissão, EXEMPLO AO ABRIR A CÂMERA ELE PEDE permissão e não mais ao iniciar o aplicativo.
Acredito que você deve tentar usar um instalador de APK para poder instalar ele, ou ajustar os pedidos de permissão, Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score -1):

Isso ocorre por não ser um aplicativo oficial da play store, pois você gerou como debug.
Nas configurações do seu celular existe uma opção para permitir instalar de fontes desconhecidas, se não estou enganado fica dentro da área de segurança.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/186464)

Comment: Claro que responde, o aviso que ele está recebendo está relacionado ao fato do dispositivo dele não ter permissão para aceitar aplicativos de fontes desconhecidas, pois ele está gerando pelo modo debug, com isso o dispositivo não possui um autor válido da play store. Tive o mesmo problema e consegui resolver da forma que relatei.

Comment: Renan, não está errado, mas isso seria totalmente um comentário. Uma resposta seria mais elaborada, com uma imagem, um exemplo do local, etc. Ainda você "supõe": "se não estou enganado fica dentro da área de segurança.". Entende o motivo da revisão? (aproveitando, eu não te dei -1 caso esteja pensando)